# Populate text field based on the selected drop down value

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have the following PHP Code that outputs the query result (which is simply a mapping of a Product Name and its corresponding unit price) to a JSON file.  The PHP code also populates the drop down list.

I have no problem in creating the JSON file and populating the drop down list. My main concern is this:

When the user selects a Product Name from the drop down list, how do I auto-populate another text field to display the Product's corresponding unit price?

```
<label for="p_name">Product Name</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="p_name" id="p_name" style="width: 300px;" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width: 300px;">
        <?php
            $connstring = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=myDB user=postgres password=password")
            or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
            $select = "SELECT p_name, unit_price FROM Product";
            $executeSelect = pg_query($select) or die('Postgresql: ' . pg_last_error());

            $result = array();

            while ($line = pg_fetch_array($executeSelect, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

                $index = 0;
                foreach ($line as $col_value) {
                    if ($index % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        //Display Product Name in the drop down list
                        echo "<li><a>$col_value</a></li>";
                        $index++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $index++;   
                    }


                }   
                //Store query output to the result array
                $result[] = $line;

            }

            //Save the query output to a JSON file
            file_put_contents('C:\Apache\htdocs\productList.json', json_encode($result), LOCK_EX);


            pg_free_result($executeSelect);
            pg_close($connstring);                                                              
        ?>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
</div><!-- /input-group -->     


<label for="unit_price">Unit Price</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="unit_price" id="unit_price"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to show the product's corresponding unit price.

**JQuery for loading the JSON file on the server.**

```
$.getJSON('products.json', function(data) {
    // process the data
});
```

For more information on `$.getJSON()`, check out [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

**Tip**: Better load the entire JSON file once in the onReady() event of the document and populate the Product name dropdown box. *Using PHP is not a good choice of design by my experience.*

Comment: why would you load the JSON file on the server?  Shouldn't the JSON file be parsed on the client side already?

Comment: The JSON file is within the `htdocs/` folder which means that it is present in the server-side. You just have to load the file into the client-side to do the processing. Also, the client-side don't have any access on the local filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that exactly? Sorry I am very new to this